# Is the Microsoft Sync Framework distributable without installation?

Tags: .net, microsoft-sync-framework

I am planning to use Microsoft Sync Framework for program update.
Can i use Microsoft Sync framework without installing it.
Just Copying Microsoft.Synchronize.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll have to use one of the Sync Framework MSIs.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd937085(v=SQL.110).aspx for details

Comment: Thank u. @Peter Ritchie. So if i want to use Microsoft Sync Framework to Sync local and remote pc. I need two computer that installed Microsoft Sync framework in both side. Is that correct?

Comment: I believe you can sync to a "simple participant" that doesn't required the sync framework to be installed (e.g. a database).

Comment: Sync Fx is only required to be installed where the sync app/code is actually running. and you can actually get away without installing it if you do some COM Registration-Free activation, wouldn't advise it though.